# pass variable form file.js.erb to _partial.html.erb rails 3.1 and jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I receive in `file.js.erb` params from a form and I render a partial `_form_new_url.html.erb`.

I have in `_form_new_url.html.erb` partial  a picture gallery with http://bxslider.com/.

I use fancybox for render the partial.

When the partial is rendered completely the user with buttons prev, and next, can get the current_image selected in partial. This is de code for this functionality in `file.js.erb` like:

```
$.fancybox('<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'form_new_url'))%>', {
  onComplete: function() {
    $('#preview_images_gallery').bxSlider({
      onAfterSlide: function(currentSlide, totalSlides, SlideObject){
        $image_selected = SlideObject.attr('src');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

`$image_selected` is the src attribute of current_image selected for user in slider.

My problem is that I need use `$image_selected` like object attribute, e.g. `@post.image_url` in partial `_form_new_url.html.erb`.

How can pass current value of `$image_selected` to partial `_form_new_url.html.erb` without reload the box **fancybox?**.

Comment: Do you mean something like that $.fancybox('<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "form_new_url", :select_image => + $image_selected + '))%>' ?

Comment: The problem was fixed. It easy pass with hidden field the variable `$image_selected` to form `<%= f.hidden_field :field_form, :id => 'image_url' %>` and add in js.erb `$('#image_url').val($image_selected);` Thank you to Marek :)